# FIle list serach by multiple keywords R

Tags: r, list, file

I have a list of files, and want to select only those with certain words that are within the file name. Is this case all files that contain "Semana"

I have this code, but unsure what to put in the pattern argument:

`malfiles11<-list.files(path = "./", pattern =  , recursive = FALSE, full.names = TRUE, ignore.case= FALSE )`

Here is a section of the list:

```
'[1] "./GBD2016_2_1000_Venezuela_MoH_Epi_2008_13.xlsxEntidades Federales10.csv"                                                               
 [2] "./GBD2016_2_1000_Venezuela_MoH_Epi_2008_13.xlsxESTADO12.csv"                                                                            
 [3] "./GBD2016_2_1000_Venezuela_MoH_Epi_2008_13.xlsxVenezuela, Semana Epidemilógica 01 hasta la semana 13 del Año 2.00811.csv"               
 [4] "./GBD2016_2_1001_Venezuela_MoH_Epi_2008_14.xlsxESTADO12.csv"                                                                            
 [5] "./GBD2016_2_1001_Venezuela_MoH_Epi_2008_14.xlsxVenezuela, Semana Epidemilógica 01 hasta la semana 14 del Año 2.00811.csv"               
 [6] "./GBD2016_2_1001_Venezuela_MoH_Epi_2008_14.xlsxVenezuela, Semana Epidemiológica 14 de 2.007, Semana Epidemiológica 14 de año 200810.csv"
 [7] "./GBD2016_2_1002_Venezuela_MoH_Epi_2008_15.xlsxESTADO12.csv"                                                                            
 [8] "./GBD2016_2_1002_Venezuela_MoH_Epi_2008_15.xlsxVenezuela, Semana Epidemilógica 01 hasta la semana 15 del Año 2.00811.csv"  '
```

Comment: in the `pattern` you put a regex that suits your needs.. like `"Semana"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` :

```
malfiles11_semana <- malfiles11[grep(pattern = "Semana",malfiles11)]
```